Should questions related to specific software be allowed?
Prompted by this question:

Pricing OANDA box options (note: after further discussion, it is clear that this question is not about how to use specific software and rather about a particular kind of option...I'll replace this when we have a better example)

Whether specific vendor questions should be allowed was slightly controversial during the definition phase (e.g. an example about Bloomberg).

Just to expand on what I said in my comment:
I could easily see the site getting overloaded with questions about "how to do x in metatrader" and so forth.  This seems like a key risk to me as the site gets started because it could drive away people with more of a theoretical focus.  
That being said, I agree with @allen and @neil that code and algorithm discussion should certainly be within the scope of the site.  
So the question that should be asked before submitting a software question: would the vendor better service this answer?

+1: "would the vendor better service this answer?" is a really nice and concise guideline

Are there any preferences on how this will mesh with SO and/or the R-finance mailing list? I am new to finance, R, and these forums (and working in a vacuum since most I come across use Stata or SAS) and don't want to throw a wrench in the works. Let's say I had a question about best practices in working with options data in R. It seems maybe too general for the mailing list and too finance specific to SO. Thoughts?

@richardh IMO, if it's a programming/algorithm question related to finance (whether R, c++, k, etc) then it should be in-scope. But if is about how to use the software itself, then it shouldn't be asked here. We are not a Bloomberg support site.

I would say R for sure, maybe keep it to "very common" or open source software
